# Как работает getchar()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Почитав в интернете, я так понял, что getchar() - это тот же std::cin, только на вход принимает 1 символ, и этот код должен вывести "Ch= + введенный символ". Почему этот код бесконечно просит ввода символов и ничего не выводит?

```
int main() {
char ch;
ch = getchar();
cout << "Ch= " << ch << endl;
system("pause");
return 0; }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про какую функцию вы спрашиваете: getch или getchar?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow getchar. Извиняюсь, просто пробовал getch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, чего ты хочешь, НО здесь проблема не в методе `getChar()`, а проблема в методе `q0()`, который вызывается в `main()`, требующий ввести символ, и если же введенный символ входит в диапазон `[A;z]` или находится за его пределом, то метод `q0()` будет вызван вновь и опять будет требовать ввести символ до тех пор, пока НЕ будет введен пробел.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int length = 0;
char ch;

void q1();

void q0() {
    ch = getchar();
    if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'z')) {
        length++;
        q0();
    }
    else if (ch == ' ') {
        q1();
    }
    else {
        length = 0;
        q0();
    }
}

void q1() {
    return; // ???
}


int main() {
    ch = getchar();
    q0();
    cout <<"Ch= "<<ch<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Исправил, извиняюсь. Все равно getch() и getchar() ведут себя одинаково

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon странно, протестил у себя, все работает.

Comment: прикрепил скрин, у меня просит ввода символов

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon а, она у тебя глобальная

Comment: она в q0 и q1 используется

Comment: отправил ссылку

Comment: я удалил методы q0 и q1, и все нормально заработало

Comment: Почему так? Я же не использовал их в main()

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon я понял, в чем штука.

но сперва объясни, что ты хочешь сделать?

Comment: Какая шутка? Это задание по теме конечные автоматы

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon ых, подожди секунду, я ток отредактирую код

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon обновил ответ

Comment: но я в мейне закомментил этот метод

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon если оператор заключен в комментарии, то он игнорируется компилятором

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon если ответ решил вашу проблему - отметьте его как принятый